# Issue implementing gradient descent

Tags: python

I'm implementing gradient descent from scratch and I've got a segment of code which is giving me trouble.

```
temp = theta_new[j]
theta_new[j] = theta_new[j] - alpha*deriv
theta_old[j] = temp
```

It's not changing `theta_new[j]`. If I print `theta_new[j]` just after the assignment of `theta_new[j]` then it gets changed, but somehow the third line in which I assign `theta_old[j]` reverts `theta_new[j]` back to initial value. I assume this has something to do with how arrays are referenced, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: You sure `alpha*deriv` isn't zero? I complete example would help us help you.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `deep copy` to copy objects and create a new memory value and a new pointer :

```
import copy
theta_old = copy.deepcopy(theta_new)
theta_new[j] = theta_new[j] - alpha*deriv
...
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html